# Error C2664 'HWND FindWindowExW (HWND, HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR)': argument 4 cannot be converted from 'bool' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the reason I get this error in code I found on the internet and edited a bit?

The code is here:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <tchar.h>

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND p = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, _T("SHELLDLL_DefView"), false);
    HWND* ret = (HWND*)lParam;
    if (p) {
        // Gets the WorkerW Window after the current one.
        *ret = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, _T("WorkerW"), NULL);
    }
    return true;
}

HWND get_wallpaper_window()
{
    // Fetch the Progman window
    HWND progman = FindWindow(_T("ProgMan"), NULL);
    // Send 0x052C to Progman. This message directs Progman to spawn a
    // WorkerW behind the desktop icons. If it is already there, nothing
    // happens.
    SendMessageTimeout(progman, 0x052C, 0, 0, SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, NULL);
    // We enumerate all Windows, until we find one, that has the SHELLDLL_DefView
    // as a child.
    // If we found that window, we take its next sibling and assign it to workerw.
    HWND wallpaper_hwnd = NULL;
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&wallpaper_hwnd);
    // Return the handle you're looking for.
    return wallpaper_hwnd;
}
```

Comment: What do you not understand in the error message?

Comment: Something on the internet is not correct?

Comment: The last 2 parameters of `FindWindowExW()` are `LPCWSTR` not bool. A `NULL` is acceptable for the final parameter so change `FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, _T("SHELLDLL_DefView"), false);` to `FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, _T("SHELLDLL_DefView"), NULL);`

Comment: It's really important to read error messages. This one tells you what is wrong. Why ask a question when you could just read the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is complaining about you passing a `bool` to the 4th parameter of `FindWindowEx()`, which is an `LPCWSTR` (`const wchar_t*`) pointer.  A `bool` is not implicitly convertible to a pointer.

When calling `FindWindowEx()` to find the `"SHELLDLL_DefView"` window, you are passing `false` in the `lpszWindow` parameter.  All of your other calls to `FindWindow()` and `FindWindowEx()` are passing `NULL` instead.

So simply change this:

```cpp
HWND p = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, _T("SHELLDLL_DefView"), false);
```

To this instead:

```cpp
HWND p = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, _T("SHELLDLL_DefView"), NULL);
```